# Add "Close" button to macOS notifications

Tags: macos, notifications, applescript, osascript

I'm using a plugin for my shell that displays a notification when a long running command has completed. [To do this on macOS, it's using AppleScript](https://github.com/franciscolourenco/done/blob/c5023a75a4e05a526db71ef00af29e0957f870be/conf.d/done.fish#L102-L103):

```
osascript -e "display notification \"$message\" with title \"$title\""
```

When this notification pops up, it has to time out to disappear; I cannot dismiss it.
This blocks me often as it covers my  browser tabs in the top right of the screen.

I've seen similar notifications that have buttons to close them, e.g. Slack message notifications.

How can I add a "Close" button to the notification?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly of interest, there's an open-source command line utility on GitHub, https://github.com/vjeantet/alerter, which allows you to do this, and to specify many more notification options on an alert-by-alert basis. Alerter gives you much more control over alerts than AppleScript's `display notification`.

[Alerter](https://github.com/vjeantet/alerter) allows you to create an alert with numerous options: a custom icon, custom button labels, up to three different kinds of actions to replace the default "show" button on the alert, a specified application or URL to open when the alert is clicked, a Reply box like when you receive an iMessage, a way to group and remove previously display alerts, and many more.

Alerter can give you complete control over the buttons displayed, per alert, by specifying options in the shell command you enter to create each alert. You can specify apps or urls to open when the alert is clicked, or, if you use multiple options in the alert, your script will have to process the text returned to determine which option was selected.

[image: Example Alerter command line and notification]

(Note: https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier is the original project Alerter was forked from. Terminal-notifier includes a few minor extra abilities that Alerter doesn't, but doesn't give you the same control over the buttons. If you want to include a lot more functionality, it might be worth reviewing both projects.)

I'm not involved with Alerter or Terminal-notifier, just a user.

Answer (score 1):

The "[Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH61-SW1)" gives an example of this.

[image: macOS notification without buttons]

[image: macOS notification with buttons]

The guide states the difference is determined by your settings.

> Notifications are shown as alerts or banners, depending on the user’s settings

To change notification settings to include buttons, go to
**System Preferences > Notifications > Script Editor > Alert Style > Alerts**

[image: AppleScript notification style]

---

It's unclear how to change the AppleScript command to include the buttons when using the default "banner" notification style. It may be possible as other applications always show their notifications with buttons.

For more info on AppleScript commands and its parameters, (1) launch Script Editor and (2) open the Standard Additions dictionary, then (3) navigate to the command’s definition.

1. [image: Script Editor dictionary]
2. [image: Standards Additions]
3. [image: Command definition]

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Dennis' answer:
You can set the style of notification on a per app basis in:

**System Preferences > Notifications > Script Editor > Alert Style > Alerts**

In the screenshot in his answer he's changing the setting for notifications generated by the 'Script Editor' app.

I had to change it in 'Automator' to get my custom scrips to have close buttons.